# Why didn't my Database.tt file generate POCO classes using PetaPoco?

Tags: c#, orm, connection-string, app-config, petapoco

I have a WebApi project that I have just started. I am trying to add a data access layer to it. I am using PetaPoco (I have a Models folder with a Generated sub-folder that has the .tt and .ttinclude files in it). However when I use 'Run Custom Tool' from the context menu to generate my Poco classes I get nothing. The resulting Database.cs file is essentially empty (the generated initial comment is there but nothing else).

I altered the .tt file to use the name of the connection string I specified in the app.config file. I tested that connection using a test.udl file. The connection is good, and the database has tables in it that have data in them.

I would really like to have Poco classes based on these tables. I really don't want to go back to EF.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you show a portion of the `.tt` that mentions the connection string as well as listing your `app.config`.  This will help us help you

Comment: By the way, I can't believe PetaPoco forces you to use `in-line SQL` statements through-out your code whose `potential for coding mistakes won't be known until runtime`. This is generally a sign of failure for any ORM if to do anything useful you must resort to this approach - that PetaPoco requires that you must do so all the time is particularly worrisome. If you are really worried about performance issues of EF (or arguably any ORM for that matter) use `SqlCommand` or better yet have a real DB layer as `stored procs`.  Regards